# @JavascriptInterface function should return value to javascript after async task is completed

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I want to perform async code and return the resulting data after async operation is completed.

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void getdata() {
  // do some async task
  return data;
}
```

Javascript:

```
data = await Android.getData();
```

I am new to android

Comment: What solution did you followed?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that directly, [according to documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) the interface has no return value.

There are some custom alternatives based on promises like [this gist](https://gist.github.com/pathnirvana/5f4c2ce100100dbc7f1cca58e877bbc0) that ended by inspiring [this library](https://github.com/andycandy-de/SimpleAndroidBridge).